# How to get the information out of a listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I want to extract the information from my listview.  I don't know how to do this.

I have 4 fields in the listview (Doctor_Name) coming from the Doctor Table, date and time for the available appointement coming from the Appointement Table.  I need to trap the doctor_Id from the Doctor table.  Can we hide a field in the listview ?   Does the listview see all the field from the LinqDataSource or only the one we define on the screen ?

here is the Appointement.aspx

```
      <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="aptId" 
        DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" >
            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                   <td>
                      <asp:Label ID="doctorNameLabel" runat="server" 
                          Text='<%# Eval("Doctor.Doctor_Name") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <asp:Label ID="dateAptLabel" runat="server" 
                         Text='<%# Eval("dateApt", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <asp:Label ID="hourAptLabel" runat="server" 
                         Text='<%# Eval("hourApt", @"{0:hh\:mm}") %>' />
                    </td>

                    <td>
                       <asp:CheckBox id="MyCheckBox" runat="server"
                            value='<%# Eval("rdvId") %>'
                            AutoPostBack="true"
                            OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>
```

Here is the Appointement.aspx.cs

```
protected void Appointement_Update()
{
    int keyAptId = 0;
    int indxChkBox = 0;
    string sDateApt = "";
    string sHourApt = "";

    foreach (ListViewDataItem item in ListView1.Items)
    {
       CheckBox MyCheckBox = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("MyCheckBox");
       if (MyCheckBox.Checked) 
       {
           keyAptId = Convert.ToInt32(ListView1.DataKeys[item.DataItemIndex].Value);


           Session["doctorName"] = ;  <== I want to extract the doctor name from the listview
           Session["doctorId"] = ;   <== I want to extract the doctor ID 


           Label myAptDate = (Label)item.FindControl("dateAptLabel");
           sDateApt = myAptDate.Text;
           Session["dateApt"] = sDateApt;

           Label myAptHour = (Label)item.FindControl("hourAptLabel");
           sHourApt = myAptHour.Text;
           Session["hourApt"] = sHourApt;
       }
     }
```

Here is the Appointement.dbml

Appointement Table  (aptId, clientId, doctorId, dateApt, timeApt, IsAvailable)
   Doctor Table  (Id, doctor_name)

Thanks all for your suggestion.

Here is how it is coming out now with the hiddenField added.

```
       <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="aptId" 
          DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" >
            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                      <asp:HiddenField ID="lblDoctorId" runat="server" 
                         Value='<%# Eval("Doctor.Id") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <asp:Label ID="doctorNameLabel" runat="server" 
                           Text='<%# Eval("Doctor.Doctor_Name") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <asp:Label ID="dateAptLabel" runat="server" 
                           Text='<%# Eval("dateApt", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <asp:Label ID="hourAptLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("hourApt", @"{0:hh\:mm}") %>' />
                    </td>

                    <td>
                       <asp:CheckBox id="MyCheckBox" runat="server"
                            value='<%# Eval("aptId") %>'
                            AutoPostBack="true"
                            OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>

           <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                      <asp:HiddenField ID="lblDoctorId" runat="server" 
                              Value='<%# Eval("Doctor.Id") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <asp:Label ID="DoctorNameLabel" runat="server" 
                         Text='<%# Eval("Doctor.Doctor_Name") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <asp:Label ID="dateAptLabel" runat="server" 
                         Text='<%# Eval("dateApt", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <asp:Label ID="hourAptLabel" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Eval("hourApt", @"{0:hh\:mm}") %>' />
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox id="MyCheckBox" runat="server"
                            value='<%# Eval("aptId") %>'
                            AutoPostBack="true"
                            OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>

 Here is how it is coming out on the screen:   
 Doctor_Name   dateApt  HourApt      choice
               DoctorA  31/01/2014   09:00  checkbox
               DoctorB  31/01/2014   09:00  checkbox
               DoctorC  31/01/2014   09:00  checkbox

 if I removed the hiddenfield from the ItemTemplate it is coming out like this
 Doctor_Name   dateApt     HourApt      choice
 DoctorA      31/01/2014   09:00      checkbox
               DoctorB   31/01/2014     09:00     checkbox
 DoctorC      31/01/2014   09:00      checkbox
```

Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already getting data from the `ListView`:

```
Label myAptDate = (Label)item.FindControl("dateAptLabel");
sDateApt = myAptDate.Text;
```

The same premise works with any other data that's stored in those UI elements.  For example, you want to get the "name" property, that's already available:

```
Label myName = (Label)item.FindControl("doctorNameLabel");
sName = myName.Text;
```

If you also want to get the "ID" from the UI then you'll need to store it in the UI first.  It could be something as simple as a hidden field:

```
<asp:Hidden ID="doctorIDLabel" runat="server" 
            Value='<%# Eval("Doctor.ID") %>' />
```

Then you can continue to use the same technique that you're already using to get its value from the UI elements.  There's nothing special or different about these fields, your existing technique will work on all of them.

Comment: thanks for your comments.  I added the changes but it comes out missy on the screen check my comments up

Comment: @user3127986: It looks like you added a `td` element to your data rows, but not to your header/footer rows.  You don't need a new `td` element.  Just put the `asp:Hidden` in any of the existing `td` elements.

Comment: in the layout template at the <th what will be the proper syntax <th hidden="doctorId" runat="server"></th>

Comment: @user3127986: You don't need to add a table cell for a hidden field.  All you'd have is an empty cell in the UI.  Just include the `asp:Hidden` in one of the cells you already have.  For example, the same cell which has the Name property.

Comment: I have 4 cells right now, DoctorName, date, time, checkbox. If I add the asp:hiddenField for doctorId it comes out all not allign in the display.  I think it is because it is missing a field in the <th definition.

Comment: @user3127986: As I said, you're *also* adding a 5th `td` cell which *you don't need to do*.  It's just a simple HTML table.  I can't be any more clear than this.  Just add the `asp:Hidden` to the existing table structure.  There's no need to change that structure.  If this isn't clear then the only recommendation I can give is for you to start with some introductory tutorials on HTML markup.  It's going to be a very useful skill in web development.

Comment: I got it sorry I am a beginner... thanks for your help now it is coming exactly how I wanted. no <td>  was needed.  Thanks again

Comment: the doctorId key is not coming out.  I tried also the AptID which also not coming out (I added them in the <td> to see if something was coming out but nothing is showing up.  Any idea ?

Comment: @user3127986: Without seeing the updated code I can't really guess.

Comment: here is the new question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413780/doctorid-key-and-aptid-key-are-not-showing-up-from-a-listview