# id key not showing up in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am trying to display the DoctorId key field in my listview and it's coming out always with blanks.

Here is the .aspx page

```
       <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" 
         ContextTypeName="AppointementDataContext" EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" 
         EnableUpdate="True" EntityTypeName="" TableName="Appointement" 
            Where="IsAvailable = True && dateApt >= DateTime.Now && doctorId = Doctor.Id &&
                   doctorid = 1"> 

            <WhereParameters>
               <asp:ControlParameter 
                   Name="doctor_name" 
                   ControlID="DropDownList1" 
                   PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                   Type="String" />
             </WhereParameters>

        </asp:LinqDataSource>

       <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="aptId" 
         DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" >
            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                  <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDoctorId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("doctorId") %>' />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="DoctorNameLabel" runat="server" 
                          Text='<%# Eval("Doctor.Doctor_Name") %>' />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <asp:Label ID="dateAptLabel" runat="server" 
                          Text='<%# Eval("dateApt", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="hourAptLabel" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Eval("hourApt", @"{0:hh\:mm}") %>' />
                  </td>

                  <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox id="MyCheckBox" runat="server"
                         value='<%# Eval("aptId") %>'
                         AutoPostBack="true"
                         OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked" />
                 </td>
                </tr>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                  <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDoctorId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("doctorId") %>' />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="DoctorNameLabel" runat="server" 
                          Text='<%# Eval("Doctor.Doctor_Name") %>' />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <asp:Label ID="dateAptLabel" runat="server" 
                          Text='<%# Eval("dateApt", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="hourAptLabel" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Eval("hourApt", @"{0:hh\:mm}") %>' />
                  </td>

                  <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox id="MyCheckBox" runat="server"
                         value='<%# Eval("aptId") %>'
                         AutoPostBack="true"
                         OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked" />
                 </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplatee>
```

All the fields are coming out with the proper values EXCEPT the doctorID.

Here is my Appointement.designer.cs

```
 public partial class Doctor : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
 {

private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new 
        PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

private int _Id;

private string _Doctor_name;

private EntitySet<Appointement> _Appointement;



 public partial class Appointement : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
 {

private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new 
             PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

private int _aptId;

private System.Nullable<int> _clientId;

private int _doctorId;

private System.DateTime _dateApt;

private System.TimeSpan _hourApt;

private System.Nullable<bool> _IsAvailable;

private EntityRef<Doctor> _Doctor;
```

The doctor Name is coming out so it is somehow connected properly.  I don't see why the doctorId or the Doctor.Id is not been displayed on the Listview.

Here is how the Appointement.dbml is define:
Appointement Table (aptId,clientId,doctorId,dateApt,hourApt,IsAvailable)
Doctor Table (Id,doctor_name)

I noticed in the Design mode for the Appointement.aspx my column DoctorId is not showing up with DataBound.  any idea on how to have it with DataBound ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somehow I don't know why I deleted the   table td definition

```
     <asp:Label ID="lblDoctorId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("doctorId") %>' />
```

and I moved them at the end of the definition and it works !!!

If it can help anyone else in the future...